# get all array keys after specific key in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this,

```
$ptJson = {
    ["phoneSMS1"]=> "mobile",
    ["phoneSMS2"]=> "mobile",
    ["phoneSMS3"]=> "mobile",
    ["phoneSMS4"]=> "mobile",
    ["phoneSMS5"]=> "main"
}
```

And I have to delete the `phoneSMS3`, so I used `unset` to unset the key

```
unset($ptJson['phoneSMS3']);
```

It worked great.! 
Now I want to move rest keys level-up by one, but don't know how.
Searched but have no luck.

So, how to find the rest array keys after `phoneSMS3`?

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the key `phoneSMS4` to `phoneSMS3`, `phoneSMS5` to `phoneSMS5`, etc?

Comment: Yes exactly want to do that. @Mureinik

Comment: That isn't php array. Php array hasn't `{}`.

Comment: Taken from fire-bug. So please forgive me for that. @Mohammad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd iterate over the keys from the position you want to remove till the end of the array and assign the following key to the current position in each iteration:

```
$prefix = 'phoneSMS';
$index = 3;

while (array_key_exists($prefix . ($index + 1), $ptJson)) {
    $ptJson[$prefix . $index] = $ptJson[$prefix . ($index + 1)];
    ++$index;
}
unset($ptJson[$prefix . $index]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for($i = 2; $i < count($ptJson); $i++){
  $ptJson[$i] = 'phoneSMS'.($i+1);
}
```

this is how you can acess it you just should use it a bit more generic

Answer (score 1):

```
$flg=0;
$i=1;
foreach($ptJson as $key=>$val){
    $i++;
    if($key =="phoneSMS3"){
        unlink($ptJson[$key]);
        $flg=1;
    }
    if($flg==1)
        $ptJson[$key]=$ptJson["phoneSMS".$i];
}
```

Comment: I want to get the rest array keys after `phoneSMS3`. You sure this will give me that?

Answer (score -1):

I think reset($array) function may help.

Comment: Can you please give an example?

Comment: http://phpflow.com/php/stepping-an-associative-array-up-one-level-on-key/